# Why is there a white line beneath my banner image?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone have any idea why there is a tiny white line between my banner image and the purple line beneath it on this page? https://www.lpp-leicester.org.uk/

I have inspected the element and I don't think there is any padding or margins touching it.

The banner image is part of my theme so I can't find the relevant code. Apologies, I'm very new to this.

Comment: Use the inspect-element for these cases. StackOverflow isn't for debugging questions, more for single code questions. That being said, remove the class `border-bottom` from `.jumbotron` and then remove the `margin-bottom` from your `.wp-bp-jumbo-overlay`

Comment: You have a border-bottom (1px). By the way, 5000 lines of CSS? Wow.

Comment: Before you ask the next question of this type, please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

It because of jumbotron class border. use

```css
.jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7a52bc !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this - how can I amend this code? It does not appear to be in the main style.css

Comment: You are welcome. Just add the the upper code below the main style.css.

Answer (score 0):

Remove following css from div below Jumbotron `div`

`background-color: #783DBC;`
`height: 5px;`

And add following css to Jumbotron `Section` tag

`border-bottom: 5px solid #783DBC !important;`

Answer (score -1):

It's because your `jumbotron` has the class `border-bottom`.

Comment: Thank you for this, Nicolas. How can I amend this code? It does not appear to be in the main style.css

Comment: This is probably part of some template in your wordpress theme. If you don't know where to search a good start would be to do a full text search for `border-bottom` in your theme.

Answer (score -3):

Just add this CSS rule to remove the tiny white line. It will do the trick

```
.container-fluid { margin-top: -1px;}
```

Comment: You are hiding the problem, not solving it. That's not a good solution.

Comment: @NicolasReynis this is just a suggestion. Relax.